# NodeJS removes or deletes Javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js

So, I have been trying to create a litte frontend to backend communication with NextJS and NodeJs.NextJS Api forks a node and this node then listens for requests i make from my api.However, my object crashes or something, idk why.

Here is the code of my node. the process.send(NET_PONG_PACKAGE); starts the communication and tells the api , he is ready for requests, so just you dont wonder. If the API sends the first message, the "message" event is triggered and an error occurs.

```
import * as Utils from './util'
import {ConnectionHandler} from "./ConnectionHandler";
import {
    KafkaMessagePackage,
    KafkaResultPackage, NET_KAFKARESPONSE_PACKAGE,
    NET_PONG_PACKAGE, NetworkPackage,
    NOT_ENOUGH_ARGUMENTS_ERROR, PACKAGECODE_PING_PACKAGE,
    SyncPackage, UNKNOWN_PACKAGE_ID, WRONG_NODE_TYPE_ERROR
} from "./Variables";
import {Manager} from "./KafkaManager";
const nprocess = require("node:process")
const prefix = "[NODEJS] "

// Argument Handling
const args:Array<string> = nprocess.argv;
const arg:string = args[2];



if(arg == undefined || arg != '-f'){
    Utils.killProcess(nprocess,NOT_ENOUGH_ARGUMENTS_ERROR);
}



class myClass  {
    public validateMyRequest(json_message:any){
        const message:NetworkPackage = json_message != undefined ? json_message : JSON.parse(json_message);

        switch (message.reqID) {
            case PACKAGECODE_PING_PACKAGE:
                this.sendProcessCreatedPackage();
                break;
            case 0:
                this.sendKafkaRequest(message);
                this.sendKafkaResponsePackage();
                break;
            default:
                this.logError(prefix + UNKNOWN_PACKAGE_ID)
                break;
        }
    }
    private sendKafkaRequest(message:any) {
        const kafkaManager:Manager = new Manager(message.hostIP);
        kafkaManager.sendMessageToKafka(message.topic,message.message);
    }

    private sendKafkaResponsePackage() {
        if(!process.send){
            this.logError(prefix + WRONG_NODE_TYPE_ERROR);
            return;
        }
        this.sendMessage(NET_KAFKARESPONSE_PACKAGE);
    }
    private sendProcessCreatedPackage(){
        this.sendMessage(NET_PONG_PACKAGE)
    }
    private sendMessage(messagePacke:KafkaResultPackage):void
    private sendMessage(messagePackage:SyncPackage):void {
        if(process.send){
            process.send(messagePackage);
        }
    }
    private logError(errorMessage:string):void{
        console.log(errorMessage)
    }

}

process.on("message", validateMyRequest)
// @ts-ignore
process.send(NET_PONG_PACKAGE);
```

This code results in following error:

```
this.sendKafkaRequest(message);
                     ^

TypeError: this.sendKafkaRequest is not a function
    at process.validateMyRequest (/Users/marvin.kaiser/kafka-producer/backend/build/myProducer.js:52:22)
    at process.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:937:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

This is the code without using an object. It works just perfectly fine If you have a clue on whats going on, please let me know.

```
import * as Utils from './util'
import {
    KafkaMessagePackage,
    KafkaResultPackage, NET_KAFKARESPONSE_PACKAGE,
    NET_PONG_PACKAGE, NetworkPackage,
    NOT_ENOUGH_ARGUMENTS_ERROR, PACKAGECODE_PING_PACKAGE,
    SyncPackage, UNKNOWN_PACKAGE_ID, WRONG_NODE_TYPE_ERROR
} from "./Variables";
import {Manager} from "./KafkaManager";
const nprocess = require("node:process")
const prefix = "[NODEJS] "

// Argument Handling
const args:Array<string> = nprocess.argv;
const arg:string = args[2];



if(arg == undefined || arg != '-f'){
    Utils.killProcess(nprocess,NOT_ENOUGH_ARGUMENTS_ERROR);
}

function validateMyRequest(json_message:any){
    const message:NetworkPackage = json_message != undefined ? json_message : JSON.parse(json_message);

    switch (message.reqID) {
        case PACKAGECODE_PING_PACKAGE:
            sendProcessCreatedPackage();
            break;
        case 0:
            logError("noch alles fein!");
            console.log("Hier soll es anscheinend zu einem Fehler kommen:");
            console.log(message);
            sendKafkaRequest(message);
            sendKafkaResponsePackage();
            break;
        default:
            logError(prefix + UNKNOWN_PACKAGE_ID)
            break;
    }
}
function sendKafkaRequest(message:any) {
    const kafkaManager:Manager = new Manager(message.hostIP);
    kafkaManager.sendMessageToKafka(message.topic,message.message);
}

function sendKafkaResponsePackage() {
    if(!process.send){
        logError(prefix + WRONG_NODE_TYPE_ERROR);
        return;
    }
    sendMessage(NET_KAFKARESPONSE_PACKAGE);
}
function sendProcessCreatedPackage(){
    sendMessage(NET_PONG_PACKAGE)
    console.log("Hier isst noch alles fein 1!")
}
function sendMessage(messagePackage:any):void {
    if(process.send){
        console.log("[NODE] Nachricht gesendet:")
        console.log(messagePackage);
    process.send(messagePackage);
}
}
function logError(errorMessage:string):void{
    console.log(errorMessage)
}
process.on("message",validateMyRequest)
// @ts-ignore
process.send(NET_PONG_PACKAGE);
```

Comment: `process.on("message", msg => validateMyRequest(msg))`

Comment: Oh wow , it was that simple huh. It works now. Thank you very much for helping me, I thought passing in process.on("message",  validateMyRequest) would be enough.

Comment: You've lost `this` reference